# Proving a Problem has a Closed Form Solution

Tags: abstract-algebra, geometry, algebra-precalculus, closed-form

I have been working on how deduce the radius of a circle based only on knowing the length of a chord within the circle and the area of the segment the chord creates. This restricts the radius to only one possibility but I can't seem to find a closed form solution for finding the radius using the given information.  I am not interested in the answer to the question but I am interested in how one would go about proving whether or not this problem and others like it  have a closed form solution.  What field should I be looking in to or papers should I be reading in order to work on proving whether or not this problem and others like it have a closed form solution or not?

Comment: @bryan Is calculus being used to prove it is solvable or not solvable?

Comment: I would consider that a closed form solution.  I would be interested to see how you found the answer so quickly.  Would you post the solution as a comment or as an answer?

Comment: Naturally I do not know the exact way you are going to approach it but I have tried both the calculus and trig approach and they have both yielded formulas that cannot be simplified.  I think if you actually try it you may find this to be the case with your approach

Comment: I take that back: as you suggest, I didn’t look quite far enough ahead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to find a mathematical description of your problem. This can be e.g. an equation, an equation system or a function. Each simple geometric shape can be described by an associated equation. For circles, it is the circle equation. If you have the equation in explict form (means in [closed form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression)), you can ask if this kind of equations can be solved explicitly (means in closed form).

You are asking for a general method for solving a given equation in closed form. There is no comprehensive method known. Here are some references for the [Elementary functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function) and for the [Liouvillian functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouvillian_function).

The problem of existence of elementary inverses of elementary functions is solved in [Ritt, J. F.: Elementary functions and their inverses. Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 27 (1925) (1) 68-90](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1925-027-01/S0002-9947-1925-1501299-9/) and in [Risch, R. H.: Algebraic Properties of the Elementary Functions of Analysis. Amer. J.
Math. 101 (1979) (4) 743-759](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2373917?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents).

It is easy to prove a theorem that is in a certain sense opposite to Ritt's theorem: If $f$ is a function with $f=f_1\circ\ldots\circ f_n$, where $n\in\mathbb{N}_{\ge 1}$ and $\forall i\in\{1,...n\}\colon f_i\colon D_i\subseteq\mathbb{C}^{k_i}\to\mathbb{C}^{k_i}$, for each partial inverse $\phi$ of $f$, $\phi=\phi_n\circ\ldots\circ \phi_1$ holds, where $\forall i\in\{1,...n\}\colon \phi_i$ is a partial inverse of $f_i$.

The question for closed-form solutions of equations that are values of elementary functions of rational numbers (the [Elementary numbers](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ElementaryNumber.html)) is asked in [Chow, T. Y.: What is a Closed-Form Number? Amer. Math. Monthly 106 (1999) (5) 440-448](http://math.mit.edu/~tchow/closedform.pdf).

The problem of solving a given ordinary equation of certain kinds in a differential field (e.g. in the Elementary functions or in the Liouvillian functions) is solved in [Rosenlicht, M.: On the explicit solvability of certain transcendental equations. Publications mathématiques de l'IHÉS 36 (1969) 15-22](https://eudml.org/doc/103891).

Another method is decribed in Khovanskii, A.: Topological Galois Theory. Solvability and Unsolvability of Equations in Finite Terms. Springer 2014 and articles of A. Khovanskii and Y. Burda. It is applied in the following article.
[Belov-Kanel, A.; Malistov, A.; Zaytsev, R.: Solvability of equations in elementary functions. Journal of Knot Theory and Its Ramifications 29 (2020) (2) 204-205](https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.10409)

I suppose all of these methods could be extended to other classes of closed-form functions.

Look also for Lambert W, Generalized Lambert W, Hyper Lambert W and Leal functions.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to make a general statement to this effect.  In your case, without writing down equations, I can already tell that your equations have a combination of $\sin{\theta}$ and $\theta$, which rarely produces closed form solutions.  Then again, some equations can surprise: today, someone posted an awful equation to which some very bright person [deduced a closed-form solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/349321/equation-8-cos3x13-162-cos-x-27/349494#349494).

One result that may have some relevance is [Liouville's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_%28differential_algebra%29) which states what kind of functions have closed-form antiderivatives.  Other than that, I know of no general statement on what may be solved with a closed form.